# SphinxSearch - Different Nodes using shared data

Tags: amazon-ec2, sphinx, amazon-efs

We are in the process of building a SphinxSearch Cluster using Amazon EC2 instances. We did a sample test like several instances using the same shared file system (Elastic File System). Our idea is, in a cluster we might have more than 10 nodes, But we can use a single instance to index documents and keep it in Elastic File System  and can shared by multiple nodes for reading.

Our test worked fine, But technically any problem with this approach? (Like locking issue etc)

Can someone please suggest on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well the two main problems I know about, is the lock file (.spl) - each searchd node will want its own one. Multiple servers accessing the same folder will get confused. And index 'rotation' each instanced expects to be able to rotate in the new index files, so orcestrating rolling 'rotates' of index is compliated. But you already said test worked, so persumable sorted out the problems anyway...

Comment: @barryhunter is it possible to rotate the index without indexing? I used a master server to index and rsync with other instances. I tried to use the indexer merge command with the same index.

`indexer --merge jobs jobs --config /var/sphinxcluster/config/sphinx_node.conf --rotate`

anything wrong with this approach? My aim is to avoid indexing in all my instances (around 15 instances).

Comment: Well merge is just creating a new index from two indexes. Not sure how that helps. doesnt seem relevent. One trick that may work is to do a standard 'rotate' based reindex in the master indexing node. One the 'slave' servers, it might just be enough to restart searchd (and if you have many reduntant nodes, doesnt matter that one goes offline at a time for reloading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're ok with having N copies of the index you can do as follows:

- build an index in one place in a temp folder
- rename the files so they include .new.
- distribute the index to all the other places using rsync or whatever you like. Some even do broadcasting with [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net)
- rotate the indexes at once in all the places by sending HUP to the searchds or better by doing RELOAD INDEX (http://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/sphinxql_reference/reload_index_syntax.html), it normally takes only few ms so we can say that your new index replaces the previous one simultaneously on all the nodes
- previously (and perhaps still in Sphinx) there was an issue with rotating the index (either by --rotate or RELOAD) in case it was processing a long query (the rotate just had to wait). It was fixed in Manticoresearch recently.

This is tried'n'true solution people use in production for years, but if you really want to share the same files among multiple searchd instances you can softlink all the files except .spl, but then to rotate the index in the searchd instances using the links (not the actual files) you'll need to restart the searchd instances which doesn't look good in general, but in some special cases may be still a good solution.

Comment: Thanks Sergey Nikolaev  for your suggestions. `manticoresearch` is an open source project?